# CCTouchDispatcher Priority issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Using CCTouchDispatcher which I initialize in my main...

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

I think this is right so far- I have dragging/dropping working and everything with my touches, but when I drag a sprite overtop of a CCMenu the touch priority is on the menu and not on the sprite anymore- is there any way to fix this?

```
gameBoard = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];
    [self addChild:gameBoard z:-1];
```

(I populate the gameBoard later)

I had it working not using the CCTouchDispatcher and the gesture recognizer, but it wasn't triggering ccTouchEnded for whatever reason so I figured I would give this a shot!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a work-around for this.

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

Just change 0 to -129 or lower. The CCMenu is priority -128 and the lower the value the higher the priority.

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-130 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

So this allows stacking of Sprites onto a CCMenu of buttons, where the Sprites are still recognizing the touches.

Answer (score 1):

That's a clever solution. But I think a better solution is you implement CCMenu yourself. As far as I know, many people use CCMenu on buttons or something you can press. But it has many limitations that you can't overcome. For example, you can't have more than one callback function on CCMenu. So I suggest you have your own class to implement it.

Here is some code in C++, hope it can help(but you still have to implement all methods, LOL):

```
class ownButton : public CCNode
{
  public:
  ownButton();

  void init(const char* normalPicPath, const char* pressedPicPath, const char* disabledPicPath, const char* basePicPath);
  bool isContainpoint(CCTouch *touch); 
  void pressed();
  void disabled();
  void normalized();
  int getStatus();
  virtual CCSize getSize();
protected:
  CCSprite* normalPicSprite_;
  CCSprite* pressedPicSprite_;
  CCSprite* disabledPicSprite_;
  CCSprite* basePicSprite_;
  int stat_;
};
```